# (setq select-enable-primary t) breaks copy/paste in Emacs 28

Tags: copy-paste, selection

After I updated Cygwin W32 to v28 selection of text started to copy the value to clipboard.

I use selection to replace existing text with one from buffer but now the text is replaced with itself because it copied to buffer on selection.

Troubleshooting with `emacs-w32 -Q` the breaking settings is:

```
(setq select-enable-primary t)
```

Entire code is:

```
(delete-selection-mode 1)

(defvar pc-select-selection-keys-only)
(defvar pc-select-meta-moves-sexps)
(when (<= emacs-major-version 23)
  ;; 1/-1, when the mark is active, the region is highlighted.
  (transient-mark-mode 1)
  ;; Order of next items is important, (assignment must done before pc-selection-mode enabled).
  (require 'pc-select)
  (setq pc-select-selection-keys-only t)  ; To avoid some key bindings as F6, etc.
  (setq pc-select-meta-moves-sexps t)
  (pc-selection-mode 1) )

(setq select-enable-clipboard t)
(setq select-enable-primary t)
```

The documentation mentions:

> E.g. it doesn’t exist under MS-Windows.

I set it unconditionally and it worked in 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27 but now I thing I need and to set it conditionally:

```
(unless (eq window-system 'w32)
  (setq select-enable-primary t))
```

Question: is it a bug that modification of `select-enable-primary` breaks stuff on non-supported platform?

Comment: When it says that it isn’t supported in Windows, it doesn’t mean Cygwin. Cygwin deliberately makes your computer more like linux. Perhaps you would just prefer the Windows build of Emacs?

Comment: Cygwin Emacs W32 is a special build of Emacs with w32 UI & Cygwin runtime. It uses native Windows UI elements (GDI app) and `window-system` reports `w32`. It is a special package with a separate launch command `emacs-w32`.

Comment: If you don't get a helpful answer here, consider posing the question to emacs-devel@gnu.org. (Sounds like some change was made, but that shouldn't require users to change things.)